# DreamFactory - Android Volley Timeout error

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to sign in with a user with my DreamFactory API by doing a POST erquest for a new session to get the token. However I'm getting a Volley tileout error...

Here is my code:

```
public void getUserToken(View view){
    final EditText editText_username = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.username_name_edittext);
    final EditText editText_password = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.password_name_edittext);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    String url = "http://my.virtual.machine/rest/user/session";

    JSONObject js = new JSONObject();

    try {
        js.put("email", editText_username.getText().toString());
        js.put("password", editText_password.getText().toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest userTokenRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,js,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        userToken = response.getString("session_id");
                        userEmail = response.getString("email");
                        Log.d("UserToken Response", "OK => " + userToken);

                        getUserData();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("ERROR","error => "+error.toString());
                }
            }

    ) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("X-DreamFactory-Application-Name", "xxx");

            return params;
        }
    };

    queue.add(userTokenRequest);

}
```

When I run a POST request from Hurl.it it all works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, the response takes some time to do, so by adding a delay it works! :)

```
int socketTimeout =5000;//5 seconds - change to what you want
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    userTokenRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

    queue.add(userTokenRequest);
```